# How can I get my usual interface when opening projects created by other people?

Tags: interface

I've bougth cup models from internet.

In the ZIP I get the blend file and pressing F12 I can render the project (Do you call it project?)

But I don't see anymore the "Layout" tab, that is what I use the most.

Why and how can I go back to my usual interface?

[image]

Like in the Opening Layout:

[image]

**UPDATE 1**

I could open the file with the default layout, however I'm not seeing the objects in there:

[image]

**UPDATE 2**

How to open Collection 1? It's grayed out.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everyone uses blender in a different way and reconfigures the user interface to their needs. The user interface is saved as part of the project.

You can load other people's projects using your own user interface this way:

Close the project.

Then go to file open, uncheck the load UI box and then open the project.

[image]

In newer versions you need to click on the gear on the top right of the window to see the LoadUI option.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, second time using Blender. And It's version 2.80 is so good.

Comment: please, see update 1.

Comment: Open collection 1

Comment: How Can I open Collection 1? It's grayed out. Should I open a new question for this?

Comment: New question indeed.