# If I open a Blender file and the UI looks weird, can I move/close the UI elements to make it look like the default?

Tags: interface

I downloaded a Blender file and opened it, and the UI looks very weird as the screen capture below. If it were other applications, like Visual Studio or something, most applications support intuitive drag-moving or closing of UI elements (like panels), but Blender works in so confusing way.

I have discovered that it has "Load UI" option in the Open dialogue, but what if I opened the file by double-clicking it. Is there a way to move/close the UI elements once it is opened, or is unchecking "Load UI" the only way?

I mean, for example, in the screen below, how can I move the Outliner from the top-left to top-right? Or How can I move the Properties from bottom to bottom-right? You know like the default Blender 2.81 UI.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use the startup.blend UI layout in older files?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2151/is-it-possible-to-use-the-startup-blend-ui-layout-in-older-files) and [interface changes with stock model files](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/162344/interface-changes-with-stock-model-files/162347#162347)

Comment: and [how can I get my usual interface when opening projects created by other people?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135110/how-can-i-get-my-usual-interface-when-opening-projects-created-by-other-people/135111#135111)

Comment: This question is marked as duplicate, but those existing anwsers that @cegaton linked are all about unchecking "Load UI" which I had already mentioned in my question. What I wanted to know was moving/closing the panels (or whatever the UI element's name is called in Blender) so that I could make them look "normal".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the top of the screen next to the layout tabs, you can click the + sign to add the layouts you are more familiar with. The default workspace is *Layout* which can be found by going to *General* > *Layout*.

To move around the existing workspaces, right-click a tab, and select *Reorder to Front* or *Reorder to Back*.

[image]

Comment: Before someone asks me why you can't move them one slot at a time, I don't know.

Comment: So, each layout is pre-programmed and fixed by Blender developers and I can only add/remove tabs? How did the author of the Blender file make that weird layout that has humorously wide Property panel?

Comment: Do you mean joining/splitting areas? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/areas.html#areas